# Does Selenium's WebElement.sendKeys(String) method, mimic 'shift' to capitalize letters?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

Does the WebElement.sendKeys(String) method mimic the function of the shift key to capitalize letters? or does it use the character code?

I recently encountered an issue when running a test where the WebElement.sendKeys(String) function is replacing a '3' with a '#' character.
This is the full String being sent: "1FADP3F24DL283164" 
The '3' between the 'P' and 'F' is the key that gets replaced with a '#' whenever the issue occurs.

I realize that the '#' character is the alternate for '3' on the keyboard, and that the '3' in my literal String was between two capitalized letters. I thought perhaps this issue could be caused by a race condition related to mimicking the shift function to capitalize letters.

This issue happens only occasionally and only on a remote IE11 driver. I have not confirmed if it occurs locally.